# Maven: How to keep a dependency version in sync within two separated maven projects

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have two maven projects, `A` and `B`. These are general independent libraries and both of them has some common dependencies (i.e. `C`). In most cases I need to import both `A` and `B` to my new projects. Here is and example of dependency tree for `myNewProject`:

```
myNewProject |
             |_ A 
             |    | 
             |    | C -> version 1.2
             |
             |_ B 
                  |
                  | C -> version 1.2
```

Is there any way to keep `C`'s version the same for both `A` and `B`. Remember these are two different projects. For example `B` **is not** a submodule of `A`.

I'm asking this question because I don't want `myNewProject` keep two different version of a dependency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `myNewProject`, declare a `<dependencyManagement>` section so that children inherit it. From the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) (which also has an example):

> The dependency management section is a mechanism for centralizing dependency information. When you have a set of projects that inherits a common parent it's possible to put all information about the dependency in the common POM and have simpler references to the artifacts in the child POMs. The mechanism is best illustrated through some examples. Given these two POMs which extend the same parent:

In the `pom.xml` of your parent project:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>C</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And then you do not need to specify the version in your children projects (`A` or `B`):

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>C</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```